# Conditionally change field value for lookup in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm trying to conditionally change field value during lookup - I have some specific order in mind and I do not want to overwrite field value, just to sort it my way. Let's say, I have class`Product` and every class object has `product_code` field. Now I want to get less than or equal, but it's not trivial - `product_code` is for most of the time like this `A01`, `B02` and so on and Django lookup `lte` would work. But now I have fields `0001C01` which I would like to be the biggest value. So during lookup I would like to add `0000` at the begining of every string that does not have this prefix, so it would look like `0001C01`, `0000B02`, `0000A01`.

Comment: You can annotate your queryset using database functions like Concat to get a new field to use in your order_by statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally annotate your queryset in order to get a new field that has de desired value and then use this field in your  `filter` or `order_by` clause. For example you could do the following:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value as V, F, Q, Case, When
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Product.objects.annotate(
    new_product_code=Case(
        When(product_code__iregex=r'^[A-Z]+.*',  # If it starts with letters  
             then=Concat(V('0000'), 'product_code', output_field=CharField())  # Then prepend four 0's
        ), 
        default=F('product_code')  # Else, the original value
    )
).filter(new_product_code__lte='whatever you like')  # Now filter by using your new value
```

Relevant parts of the documentation are [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions), [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/) and [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#iregex)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds fairly straightforward.  Fetch the desired `Product` objects, and for each one, prepend `0000` to `product_code` if it doesn't start with that string.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(some_query_expression)
for product in products:
    if not product.product_code.startswith('0000'):
        product.product_code = '0000' + product.product_code
```

It's not clear if you want to save this value back to the database, or just use it for temporary comparisons.  If you do want to save it, call `product.save()`.

Comment: I do not want to overwrite the original value nor change it, just to conditionally modify it for the time of lookup.